# Unity NetCode - How to call a function when a server or client connects

Tags: unity, networking

I want to do a number of things after calling the functions `NetworkManager.Singleton.StartHost()` and `NetworkManager.Singleton.StartClient()`.

Is there a hook or something to do this?

Comment: The "below functions" are... the same functions. Is this correct, or is it a typo?

Comment: Thanks for catching. Yes one was supposed to be Client. Corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods that can be registered: [OnClientConnectedCallback](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/api/Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager/index.html#onclientdisconnectcallback) and [OnServerStarted](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/api/Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager/index.html#onserverstarted).

As an example for registering OnClientConnectedCallback, you would do the following:

```
private void Start()
{
    if (IsClient)
    {
        NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientConnectedCallback += OnClientConnected;
    }
}
```

And then define the callback

```
private void OnClientConnected(ulong clientId)
{
    if (clientId == NetworkManager.Singleton.LocalClientId)
    {
        Debug.Log("Client connected. You can now call ServerRpc methods.");
        // Call your ServerRpc method here or trigger an event to notify other scripts
        CallYourServerRpc();
    }
}
```

Make sure the class with the above inherits from NetworkBehaviour and that it has a NetworkObject component